# Format a float to display in a string with two digits?

Tags: iphone, ios, floating-point

```
NSString *timerend = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f:%.0f:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
```

So I have this string and a bunch of floats.  For example, say seconds = 6.54.  It will display as that.  I want it to display as 06.54.  Is there anyway to do that?  Any help with be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand what you want. What the time format you're looking for? Give us an example. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you want the format 'XX:XX:XX.XX' you can use the following code:

```
    NSString *timerend = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02.0f:%02.0f:%05.2f", hours, minutes, seconds];
```

When formatting float the number before the point (05) determines the minimum total characters in the entire string, not just the bit before the point.

Comment: Nope. If you check the comment, %05.2f ensures that there will be at least 5 chars in the ENTIRE string. So, 1.23 = 01.23 (the dot counts as 1 char). If you enter 12222.123, then the entire number will be presented. Try the sample, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach is to have a separate **NSString** having content `0` and append it with `timerend`. There might even be other better solutions.

```
NSString *startTag = @"0";
// Your string variable. i.e., timerend

NSString *newTime = [startTag stringByAppendingString:timerend];
```

However, you need to append only when the hour is less than 10.

Comment: @KingofBliss: I don't understand the wrong. If the programmer needs a leading `0` then, I think he should append it to the current string. What do you think I misunderstood ? Though the subject line and the matter presented is a bit confusing too.

Comment: Your solution will also append 0 if the number is 16, according to yours the o/p will be 016

Comment: I included a comment saying - `However, you need to append only when the hour is less than 10.`